# Ethereum pudding transaction hash

Tags: truffle, pending-transactions, ether-pudding

Is it possible to get the transaction hash of a function call in Ethereum Pudding/ Truffle?. It seems that it works straight forward with *web3* but Pudding is hiding it?

Comment: You can manually put the transaction together. It is not very difficult. It's 4 bytes hash(function name) + arguments as int256s all concatenated in the transaction data field.